# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider'

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, flexslider

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();      
**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider'**
});
```

I read here that error means that I either have two listings of jQuery or I don't have the necessary plugin. I don't see a second enqueue for jQuery in my functions or head etc, So I'm thinking I did the latter? I'm just starting in Treehouse on Wordpress development so patience is appreciated for this one.

Here's my functions.php

```
<?php

//Load the Theme CSS
function theme_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'grid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/grid.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'googlefonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy:400,400italic' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'social', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/webfonts/ss-social.css' );

    wp_register_style( 'flex-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    if( is_page( 'home' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('flex-stylesheet');
    }

}

//Load the Theme JS
function theme_js() {

    wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array(), '2.1', false );
    if( is_page( 'home' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
//jquery from google cdn
     wp_deregister_script('jquery');
     wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.3');
     wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );

//Enable custom menus
add_theme_support( 'menus' );

function create_widget( $name, $id, $description ) {
    $args = array(
        'name'          => __( $name ),
        'id'            => $id,
        'description'   => $description,
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<h5>',
        'after_title'   => '</h5>' 
    );

    register_sidebar( $args );

}

create_widget( 'Left Footer', 'footer_left', 'Displays in the bottom left of footer');

create_widget( 'Middle Footer', 'footer_middle', 'Displays in the bottom middle of footer');

create_widget( 'Right Footer', 'footer_right', 'Displays in the bottom right of footer');


?>
```

Here's my front-page.php:

```
<?php get_header('header.php'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="featured" class="clearfix flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">

        <?php 

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'work'
            );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li style="background-color:<?php the_field( 'background_color' ); ?>;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="grid_6">
                <img src="<?php the_field( 'homepage_slider_image' ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?> Project Screenshot">
            </div>
            <div id="featured-info" class="grid_4 omega">
                <h3 style="color: <?php the_field( 'button_color' ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_field( 'description' ); ?></p>
                <a class="btn blue" style="background-color: <?php the_field( 'button_color' ); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Project &rarr;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="grid_12 omega">
            <h5>Featured Post</h5>
        </div>

        <?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category_name' => 'featured',
                'posts_per_page' => 1
            );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="push_2 grid_10 omega clearfix">
            <article>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

            </article>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        <div class="grid_12 content clearfix">
            <div class="grid_6 recent-post">
                <article>
                    <h5>Recent Posts</h5>
                    <?php

                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'cat' => '-5',
                            'posts_per_page' => 1
                        );

                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    ?>

                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'post' ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                </article>

            </div>
                <?php 

                    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'work',
                    'posts_per_page' => 1
                    );

                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    ?>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'work' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>


<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'testimonials' ); ?>

<?php get_footer('footer.php'); ?>
```

Who knows... maybe it's two listings of jQuery. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to source `jquery.min.js` before sourcing `jquery.flexslider-min.js`.

Comment: So I switched those, but the flexslider still isn't coming up. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:
wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array(), '2.1', false );

to:
wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flexslider.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

you are probably not calling the right file name.

Cheers,